# C struct variable not reflecting change

Tags: c, struct

I am attempting to fill in a struct I have created in C, and for whatever reason it is not being reflected when I set a struct's parameters to 0. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
struct Quad head_Quad, *temp_Quad;

head_Quad.ll_x = 0.0;
head_Quad.ll_y = 0.0;
head_Quad.side_length = 600;
temp_Quad = &head_Quad;
printf("head quad length: %d \n", head_Quad.side_length);
printf("temp quad length: %d \n", temp_Quad->side_length);
```

The printf is giving me 0. (temp was just an attempt to test if the value was set again)

Below is the struct itself:

```
typedef struct Quad
{
    double ll_x;    //lower left x point
    double ll_y;    //lower left y point
    double side_length;
}Quad;
```

Comment: oh boy :) thanks buddy @xing

Comment: Note that good compilers will warn you about such mismatches.  For example, GCC with `-Wall` will do that.  If you're using GCC, add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to your command line.

Comment: Turn compiler warnings on. Leave the switch on forever.

Answer (score 1):

As @xing stated it was just the flag i was using in the printf statement, i should've known i had a for loop iterating through. Simple goof.

Instead of %d it should be %f